# Add value based on column value and group in SQL query.

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that looks like this :

```
  Date|  **Delaytype|Delay Hours**
         enginerring     1
         engineering     2
         human error     2
         human error     1
```

What do I need to query with PHP TO GET a result that gives me, for example from the above data : **engineering 3
                      Human error 3**

I was using following **SQL Query**:

```
"SELECT Delaytype, COUNT(1) as cnt FROM delays GROUP BY Delaytype"
```

This was giving me the total occurrences i.e `engineering 2, human error 2`.

To get a date involved can I add on `"WHERE BETWEEN date 1 AND date 2"`

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You need to use `SUM()` not `COUNT()`, since `COUNT()` is returning the number of rows, not the SUM of those queried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT Delaytype, SUM(`Delay Hours`) AS cnt FROM delays GROUP BY Delaytype
```

Comment: That worked perfectly - How would I incorperate a date clause i.e between two dates?  If you do not feel like awnsering I will post another question. Thanks for your help

Comment: You got it almost correct, like this: `WHERE Date BETWEEN '2012-01-15' AND '2012-01-20'`.  Add this before the `GROUP` clause